# Django can an appname be the same as its model name

Tags: python, django

For example, I have an app called **Apple**. Can the model inside its models.py be also called **Apple**?

ex: `class Apple(models.Model)` (same case).
Will I face any problems later on in referencing it or will django do? (any impossible to solve ones).

Comment: Normally the app name is the same as the module name, and these are, by PEP-8 styling guide in `snake_case`, so I would not name your app `Apple`, but `apple`.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But that's why I'm asking the question since I already have a project and changing the app names is a big hassle.